# Making a nice table

Tags: tables

I have made following table which is not looking elegant. Could anybody help me in making it more better. Following is the tex code that I have used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath, times, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, times, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\small \caption{\small Computation of number of iterations and error norms for Example 4.2:}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
\hline
 Value of $\beta$ &  $k$  & $\|A^{-1} - X_{k}\|_2$ & $\|X_k  - X_{k-1}\|_2$   \\ [0.3ex] % inserts table
 &  & & &   &  & \\
 %
\hline
 0.9  & 0  &  0.489897948556636  & 0.462668212869655  \\
 & 1 &   0.044911860348910 & 0.044385148438250 \\
 & 2 &  6.418447480230614e-004 & 6.417891668548070e-004  \\
 & 3 &   5.683044758299918e-008 &   5.683044739894235e-008  \\
 & 4 &   1.861900614935455e-016 &   1.861900614935455e-016  \\
 & 5 &   0 &   0 \\  [1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: After running it looks like this]

Comment: Are the 15 digits all significant?

Comment: @egreg Ya they are significant. I have to use them.

Comment: I told you, that 15th digit was a 8 not an 9, your fired.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems a job for `booktabs` and `siunitx`. The first provides good horizontal rules with appropriate spacing, the second is specialized in typesetting numbers with or without units of measure.

Type `S` columns make alignments at the decimal point; one can specify the number format:

```
table-format=1.15
```

means one digit for the integer part and 15 for the fractional part;

```
table-figures-exponent=2
```

means "keep two digits for the exponent";

```
table-sign-exponent=true
```

means that the exponent can be negative.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % better than "times"
\usepackage{booktabs} % pretty tables
\usepackage{siunitx}  % number formatting

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering\small 

\caption{Computation of number of iterations and error norms for Example 4.2}
\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  c
  *{2}{
   S[table-format=1.15,
     table-figures-exponent=2,
     table-sign-exponent=true]
  }
}
\toprule
Value of $\beta$ &
  $k$ &
  {$\|A^{-1} - X_{k}\|_2$} &
  {$\|X_k  - X_{k-1}\|_2$} \\
\midrule
0.9 & 0 &  0.489897948556636      & 0.462668212869655      \\
    & 1 &  0.044911860348910      & 0.044385148438250      \\
    & 2 &  6.418447480230614e-004 & 6.417891668548070e-004 \\
    & 3 &  5.683044758299918e-008 & 5.683044739894235e-008 \\
    & 4 &  1.861900614935455e-016 & 1.861900614935455e-016 \\
    & 5 &  0                      & 0                      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I am running tex code It is saying Enter file name.

Comment: The `table-format` option is just a wrapper/parser for various `table-` keys, one can also use `table-format=1.15e-2`.

Comment: @srijan What file doesn't LaTeX find?

Comment: I get `ERROR: Package xkeyval Error: "table-format" undefined in families "key".`  I get the same with the two others as well.  However, @srijan could also get `ERROR: LaTeX Error: File "newtxtext.sty" not found`.

Comment: @PålGD I'm afraid you have an outdated TeX distribution

Comment: @egreg I am getting following tex error file newtxttext.sty file not found.

Comment: @egreg Also, tex command \toprule \midrule are not working. Could you tell me why it is happening?

Comment: @srijan It means that your TeX distribution is very incomplete.

Comment: @egreg Did you mean I need new version of winedit?

Comment: @srijan WinEdt is an editor. Install the full MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: @egreg Just now I checked it is miktex 2.9 installed in my system. I dont know what is going wrong. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @srijan You probably haven't a *full* MiKTeX.